# Python,child unable to inherit function from parent

Tags: python

I have created a python code where Apple is parent class and Macbook is child class.
I can't call background() function from mackbookpro instance as mentioned below.
Getting error : AttributeError: 'Macbook' object has no attribute 'year_established'.

If i declare *year_established* out of `__init__` function it works fine.

Why can't I get data that mentioned in the parent constructor function at child component instance ?

```
class Apple:

    # year_established=1976 --code run successfully if I declare value here  
    # -- but I commented out

    def __init__(self):
        self.year_established=1976

    def background(self):
        return ('it is established in {}'.format(self.year_established))

class Macbook(Apple):

    def __init__(self):
        self.price = 10000

    def productdetails(self):
        return (str(self.price) + self.background())

macbookpro = Macbook()

print(macbookpro.productdetails())
```

Comment: You need to call the superclass initialiser - `super().__init__()`.

Comment: `year_of_manufacture` is not in the code. Are you confusing it with `year_established`?

Comment: It worked now, I have to add super() with child constructor function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the parent class initializer to the child class initializer, like :

```
class Apple:
    def __init__(self):
        self.year_established = 1976

    def background(self):
        return ('it is established in {}'.format(self.year_established))


class Macbook(Apple):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.price = 10000

    def productdetails(self):
        return (str(self.price) + self.background())


macbookpro = Macbook()

print(macbookpro.productdetails())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Base-Class (or iterface) / Inherit-Class` insted of `Child / Parent`, that whuld describe a "ownership" of classes like in this example

```
class Apple:
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent

class Macbook(Apple):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Macbook, self).__init__(**kwargs)

macbookpro = Macbook()
macbookpro_child = Macbook(parent=macbookpro)
```

The reason why a `super()` method deeded is becouse in python when a class inherits a base and a method already exists in the base class the method whuld not be changed, in other languages is diferent becouse overrides de base clase insted of ignoring the duplicate.
To fix this the super calls the original method and this can be done at any point in the `__init__()`, note that any method that you raplace from de base class have a super.
(Passing self is required to give context of in which class is the super executed)

Loocking at the old super method it can be a little more intuitive

```
class Macbook(Apple):
    def __init__(self):
        Apple.__init__(self)
```

This is your code with a super

```
class Apple:
    def __init__(self):
        self.year_established = 1976

    def background(self):
        return 'it is established in {}'.format(self.year_established)

class Macbook(Apple):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Macbook, self).__init__()
        self.price = 10000

    def product_details(self):
        return str(self.price) + self.background()

macbookpro = Macbook()

print(macbookpro.product_details())
```